# Openshift and Play Framework (on Debian Linux)

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3.2, playframework, redhat, openshift

I am deploying my app in OpenShift of RedHat; this application is play framework.

I'm following the [tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/supporting-play-framework-on-openshift-with-the-diy-application-type).

I have the next problem when using `git push`

```
root@debian:~/dev/play# git push
Counting objects: 13, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.85 KiB, done.
Total 7 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping DIY cartridge
remote: Error: OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR not defined
remote: Error: OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR not defined
remote: Starting application play
remote: Starting DIY cartridge
remote: Error: OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR not defined
To ssh://52290b27e0b8cdc2270001aa@play-unmsm.rhcloud.com/~/git/play.git/
   de310aa..9dcfe59  master -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

> remote: Error: OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR not defined

The `OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR` is not defined, so the hook fails.

Take a look at your `.openshift/action_hooks/start` to see if you're defining `OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR` or `OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR`.

There appears to be a discrepancy between the two, as seen in [this
 issue](https://github.com/opensas/play-example/pull/10) on Github

Comment: Thanks  (Y), muito obrigado.